# java - stop an endless loop function by a thread

Tags: java

My problem is:

```
public class Ex3_tester {

/** This class represents a basic implementation for Ex3testing file. */

public static double ENDLESS_LOOP=0.4;

public static void main(String[]args){

    Ex3 ex3=new Ex3();

    long n=33333331L;
    boolean ans=ex3.isPrime(n,1);
    System.out.println("n="+n+" isPrime "+ans);
}

/** DONOT change this function!,it must be used
 * byEx3-isPrime(long,double) */

public static boolean isPrime(long n){
    boolean ans=true;
    if(n<2)throw new RuntimeException("ERR: the parameter to the isPrime function must be >1 (got "+n+")!");
    int i=2;
    double ns=Math.sqrt(n) ;
    while(i<=ns&&ans){
        if (n%i==0)
            ans=false;
        i=i+1;
    }

    if(Math.random()<Ex3_tester.ENDLESS_LOOP)//responsible to enter the program into endless loop
        while(true);

    return ans;
}}
```

ok, in Ex3_tester i have a function isprime which determine if the number is prime or not. as you can see the function turn into an endless loop sometimes.

I need to try and create a wrapper to this function - if 'isprime' dont turn a result after sometime i need to close it. I have tried everything. my best code until now sometimes get the answer, but if the function turn into endless loop it throws an exception but i see that the program continue to run (i can see that in Eclipse console).
here is my code until now:

```
   package threads_task3;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Ex3 implements Callable<Boolean>{

    static long number;
    AtomicBoolean interrupt=new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public Boolean isPrime(long n, double d) {


        number=n;

        long time=(long)(d*1000);

        ExecutorService primeFunction=Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

        Future <Boolean> result=primeFunction.submit(this);

        try {

            Boolean finalresult= (result.get(time, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

            if(finalresult!=null){

                primeFunction.shutdown();
                return finalresult;
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {

            interrupt.set(true);
            primeFunction.shutdown();


            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        throw new RuntimeException();

    }

    @Override
    public Boolean call() throws Exception {

        while (!interrupt.get())
        return Ex3_tester.isPrime(number);

        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: The solution to this problem involves changing `isPrime`, so why is there a comment saying not to change it? Is this a requirement from a teacher?

Comment: yes. we are not alowed to change it.

Comment: Has your teacher read this page? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: Are you allowed to multithread this code?

Comment: o.k what is your suggestion  Robin Green?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)

Comment: we can multithread Tellus

Comment: Maybe it's possible to use `awaitTermination` with `ExecutorService`. Will try it a bit later to check if it works out.

Comment: i already tried it doesnt work and i dont know why... )-:

Comment: Zharf -  'setDaemon' works! it's not the best way but it works.. thanks

Comment: @RespectEverybody I added an answer showing how you'd do this using the standard libraries (`ExecutorSerive` and `Future`), instead of timing and interrupting manually.

Answer (score 1):

To stop this function you have no choice but to set a time limit to its execution. If it spends more than `k` seconds executing, it should have found the result and returned already. Java has a somewhat awkward multithreading model, so doing this takes a few lines of code, but there is support for it:

```
static class PrimeWrapper implements Runnable {
    long n;
    boolean result;

    PrimeWrapper(long n){
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override public void run() {
        result = isPrime(n);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long n = 7;
    PrimeWrapper isPrime = new PrimeWrapper(n);
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future future = executor.submit(isPrime);

    try {
        future.get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (Exception e) { // If future could not get() the result
        future.cancel(true);
        executor.shutdownNow();
        System.out.println("isPrime went in to an infintie loop. Exiting...");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    future.cancel(true);
    executor.shutdownNow();
    System.out.println("Is " + n + " a prime number: " + isPrime.result);
}
```

And finally I should mention that you should probably never write code like `isPrime(long n)` yourself (even in the practical domains in which equivalent time complexity may be unavoidable).

Comment: @RespectEverybody You're welcome. If this answers your question, please consider accepting it as the answer (using the checkbox to the left). Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks for the help

i tried this one and its worked :

```
package threads_task3;
public class Ex3 implements Runnable{

    static long number;
    static Boolean result=null;

    public Boolean isPrime(long n, double d) {


        number=n;

        long time=(long)(d*1000);

        Thread prime=new Thread(this);
        prime.setDaemon(true);

        long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
        prime.start();
        long end=System.currentTimeMillis();

        while( (end-start)<=time){

            if (result!=null)
                return result;

            end=System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        throw new RuntimeException();




    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        result=Ex3_tester.isPrime(number);

    }
}
```

But, it is not the best solution because if i try to wrap the function in big value of time let say 10 seconds it take a lot of resources from the computer if someone have a better idea or another way i will be happy to get it!

thanks!